# Cannot see installed extension

Tags: extension

Hello I using drupal 7 and civicrm 5.6.1

I am trying to use Postcode Lookup for Webform https://github.com/compucorp/webform_civicrm_postcode/blob/master/README.md

But I cannot see the extension after uploading it to the directory and refreshing

I have done the following.

1) Checked the directory it is installed in sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext/  and checked the settings upload directory path (custom_ext) and resource url (sites/default/files/civicrm/custom_ext)

2) Cleared the civicrm cache and the drupal cache and pressed refresh (many times)

3) Viewed the extension page via view source to see if it isn't rendering on the page

4) Read the read me to see if there is anything different that I have to do

5) Checked the file permisions - it is the same as the other extensions in the folder.

Any ideas what to check next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear how embarrasing - its a drupal module not an extension!